# @RestController retorna para mesma página mas com URL diferente

Tags: java, rest, controller, thymeleaf

Estou usando @RestController para gerenciar diferentes forms/ações em uma mesma página(com Thymeleaf), e está funcionando adequadamente, mas ao chamar método (disparado através de botão na página) ao retornar para a página a URL no navegdor não é 'resetada' mesmo se eu recrio meu ModelAndView every time:

Examplo:
URL inicial: `http://localhost:8090/project/v1/controller/`

URL após alguma ação no RestContorller: `http://localhost:8090/project/v1/controller/actionA`

URL desejada ao retornar à página após método disparado por botão: `http://localhost:8090/project/v1/controller/`

Código:
    //método que utilizo para abrir a página
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView index(){
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.addObject("myObj", this.someMethods());
            mav.setViewName("index"); //minha página
            return mav;
    }

```
//método disparado pelo botão na página, contendo a ação
@RequestMapping(value = "/actionA", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, params = "action=actionA")
    public ModelAndView actionA(...) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("myObj", this.someMethods());
        mav.setViewName("index"); //a mesma página
        return mav;
}
```

Não posso usar o mesmo parâmetro 'value' pois uso ele em meus forms/actions para definiar que método disparar na minha restcontroller, exemplo:

```
<form id="action" method="POST" th:object="${Object}"
              th:action="@{/v1/emulador-central/action}">
...
   <button type="submit" name="action" value="actionA" class="btn btn-primary">Aprovar</button>
   <button type="submit" name="action" value="actionB" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;">Reprovar</button>
...
</form>
```

Eu tentei usar redirect e não deu certo, também tentei criar um método POST para criar a  ModelAndView e então retornar isso apra minha página index, outra falha.
Alguém pode me orientar como fazer funcionar apropriadamente?
Obrigado.

Comment: Caso alguém esteja encarando o mesmo problema: até o momento não achei a solução esperada, quando encontrar atualizo.

Answer (score 0):

Tente isto:

```
<form id="action" th:action="@{/v1/emulador-central/}">
   <button type="submit" th:name="action" th:value="actionA" class="btn btn- 
     primary">Aprovar</button>
   <button type="submit" th:name="action" th:value="actionB" class="btn btn-primary" 
     style="float:right;">Reprovar</button>
</form>

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView index(@RequestParam(value = "action", required = false) String action){
        //system.out.println(action);
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("myObj", this.someMethods());
        mav.setViewName("index"); //a mesma página
            return mav;
    }
```

Comment: Opa @Kaique, pelo que entendi sua sugestão seria no método **index**, certo? Pelo jeito não fui claro (vou editar a pergunta) mas esse método eu uso para abrir a tela inicialmente, me gerando a url que desejo, certinho. Meu problema é que ao disparar um dos botões de algum form, vou para o segundo método, no caso o **actionA**, que também faz o que desejo (com service e client próprios), mas concatena a ação na url, este é o ponto que estou tentando ajustar.
Mesmo assim, tentei realizar o ajuste (no **actionA**) conforme indicou e não tive sucesso.